# Passing next and previous date using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, date

Im trying to wrap my head around this, using Jquery I want to browse a list of events by date. Im calling the php that gives me back results via jquery ajax call. I want to have 2 links that allow me to move forward in the date and the other link lets me go back in the date based on the current date being used and pass it to the php page to grab all results for that date.

So for example the default date is today, then I can click a link that will get the next day date and pass it to the php page via ajax. Then if I click the arrow again it will get the next day and so on. Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier way is to convert your date in a timestamp and send it to js => php, or php => js.

Look the Date object in js, and the date object in php. You can easily convert a timestamp to a date and a date to a timestamp.

Comment: Ok, how would I keep track of the current date though? So if the default date is today, I click the next button then I want to pass tomorrows date. Then after that if I click the previous button I want to go back to todays date. If I click next twice it goes forward 2 days, then I click previous one time it goes back one day.

Comment: You don't reload the page right ? So the the date variable is still the same in js. You begin with: var date_obj = new Date();. You do a date_obj.time() to get the today timestamps, do date_obj.getDay() to get today int. If you want to go to tomorrow you do date_obj.setTime(date_obj.getTime() + day); with day = 24 * 60 * 60. I'm sure you can use the date lib to get the next day, but that should work.

Comment: Sorry it's set getDate() & setDate() to get the today int (day in the month). juste look at the doc, there is a lot functionality.